# spring boot not able to inject spring service in spring test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, springmockito

I have been struggling to solve this problem but no luck, also I am a bit new to spring boot. This application is a user registration application.

I have a service,controller class as below

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserService {
    .....
}




@RestController
@RequestMapping("${" + Constants.USER_ROOT + "}")
public class UserController {
   @PostMapping("${" + Constants.REGISTER_URL + "}")
   public @ResponseBody Object register(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult,HttpServletRequest request) {
                .....
    }
}
```

I am writing test cases for the controller as below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { UserManagementServiceApplication.class })
public class UserControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @MockBean
    private User user;

    @MockBean
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${" + Constants.USER_ROOT + "}" + "${" + Constants.REGISTER_URL + "}")
    private String registerUrl;

    @Value("${" + Constants.USER_ROOT + "}" + "${" + Constants.CONFIRM_REGISTER_URL + "}")
    private String confirmRegisterUrl;

    @Value("${" + Constants.USER_ROOT + "}" + "${" + Constants.RESET_PASSWORD_URL + "}")
    private String resetPasswordUrl;

    @Value("${" + Constants.USER_ROOT + "}" + "${" + Constants.CONFIRM_RESET_URL + "}")
    private String confirmResetPasswordUrl;

    private String email;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        user = new User();
        email = "test" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "@test.com";
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setFirstName("TestFirstName");
        user.setLastName("TestLastName");
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("Newuser@123"));
        user.setEnabled(false);
        user.setConfirmationToken("TestConfirmationToken");
    }

    @Test
    public void createValidUserTest() throws Exception {

        JSONObject testJSON = new JSONObject();
        testJSON.put("email", email);
        testJSON.put("password", "Newuser@123");
        testJSON.put("firstName", "TestFirstName");
        testJSON.put("lastName", "TestLastName");

        // Mock
        when(userService.findByEmail(email)).thenReturn(null);
        when(userService.saveUser(user)).thenReturn(user);
        when(userService.isUserExist(Constants.EMAIL, user.getEmail())).thenReturn(false);
        when(userService.isPasswordWeak(user.getPassword())).thenReturn(false);
        when(userService.encodePassword(user.getPassword())).thenReturn("Newuser@123_encoded");
        when(userService.getProperty(Constants.USER_ROOT)).thenReturn(env.getProperty(Constants.USER_ROOT));
        when(userService.getProperty(Constants.CONFIRM_URL)).thenReturn(env.getProperty(Constants.CONFIRM_URL));

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(registerUrl).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(testJSON.toString())).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

    }
}
```

but when I am running spring boot application, its throwing some strange error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:226) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) [spring-boot-test-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration.methodValidationPostProcessor(ValidationAutoConfiguration.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted

2018-06-18 12:32:02.690 ERROR 8884 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@29d3d0fb] to prepare test instance [com.lti.resource.UserControllerTest@2125535d]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413) [surefire-booter-2.21.0.jar:2.21.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:226) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration.methodValidationPostProcessor(ValidationAutoConfiguration.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

please help me understand and resolve this error.

Comment: `User` will not be injected if you are using `user = new User();`

Comment: Why you mock User? it is entity not a bean

Comment: @MountainKing what should I do then, please suggest.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I believe that is a mistake but thats not the real problem here because even after removing new User its throwing the same error

Comment: Why you are using @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { UserManagementServiceApplication.class })?
As I can see you mock all beans so you can use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) instead.

Comment: @MountainKing, everything is working fine if I remove this service mocking in the test class and yes I tried with MockitoJUnitRunner also, not working.

Comment: why you need this line mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();?

Can you change it to MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).build();
You need to mock mvc in order to test UserController so create standalove setup for that controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173318/discussion-between-saching-and-mountain-king).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. the problem is org.springframework.core.env.Environment in UserControllerTest.

This can not be mocked but autowired.

so changing

```
 @MockBean
 private Environment env;
```

to

```
@Autowired
 private Environment env;
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: glad i could help